# How to make G++ report about Int to Bool conversion?

Tags: c++, g++, type-conversion, warnings

Can i enable some options in g++ compiler (version 4.8.5), so that it throw warning for code:

```
if (1) {}
```

Where implicit conversion (`int` to `bool`) happened.
As far as i understand, `-Wconversion` ignored such conversions and this option unfortunately unsuitable.

For what i need this?
Recently i made a typo like this:

```
if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1]) {/* DO1 */}
if (c[0] == d[0] && c[1] == d[1]) {/* DO2 */}
if (e[0] == f[0] && e[1] && f[1]) {/* DO3 */}
//must be e[1] == f[1] condition
```

And it will be useful if compiler will warn me about such cases.

Comment: This conversion is sanctioned by standard and is widely used. I doubt there is a warning for this. Solution to your problem, though, is to get rid of  nasty ifs and structure your code better.

Comment: @SergeyA But adding such flag that check all type conversion (for example `-Wconversion-all`), will be useful. Doesn't matter if it sanctioned by standard or not. If you want compile-time warnings for preventing such situations - you can enable this flag. Otherwise - not enable.

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin - with such a flag, the folks who insist on enabling all warnings and eliminating all of them will turn C++ into Pascal.

Comment: @PeteBecker Why C++ turn into Pascal? It's your choice - use this option or not. I'm surprised, that i can enable `-Wfloat-equal` option, but can't enable strict implicit type conversion check. I think both of this warnings some coders want to ignore. But, on the other hand, both of this warnings will be helpful.

Comment: Since all of the operations are checking for equality then you can use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to create a tuple and check the equality like `std::tie(e[0], e[1]) == std::tie(f[0], f[1])`.  Might not really be useful here but I figured I would point it out.

Comment: All G++ options can be listed with `g++ --verbose --help`. If an option you need is not there, it's not there.